# Is it possible to reload a website if the window width is for more than 0.2 seconds under 1000px?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some issues width a code and would like to solve a problem with a trick.

The idea would be:
The page should reload if the window size is for more than 0.2 seconds smaller than 1000px.

Here is a beginning:

```js
var width = $(window).width();

$(window).resize(function() {
    if (width > 1000 && $(window).width() < 1000) {
        location.reload();
    }
    else if (width < 1000 && $(window).width() > 1000) {
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Would be very thankful for help!

Comment: yes, it is possible ... check the width 0.21 seconds after the resize event

Comment: @jstola Cool! Can you show me how to do it?

Comment: Doesn't seem very user friendly. What is the higher level problem you are trying to solve by doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 1000) {
      location.reload();
    }
  }, 200);
});
```